# Is it possible to make pug each inside an array in a script?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have such a variable in a separate projectTemplate.pug:

```
-
    var projectTemplate = [
        { full: full250, tiny: tiny250, class: classPhotoset }, 
        { full: full249, tiny: tiny249, class: classPhotoset }, 
        { full: full248, tiny: tiny248, class: classPhotoset }, 
        { full: full247, tiny: tiny247, class: classPhotoset }
    ]
```

Outside of the script, I could do something like this:

```
div
    each photo in projectTemplate
        a(class=photo.class)(href=photo.full)
            img(src=photo.tiny)
```

Is it possible to do `each` inside a script?

It should be output like this:

```
script.
    availableImgs = [
        { src : "#{src=tiny250}", href : '#{src=full250}', class : '#{src=classPhotoset}'},
        { src : "#{src=tiny249}", href : '#{src=full249}', class : '#{src=classPhotoset}'},
        { src : "#{src=tiny248}", href : '#{src=full248}', class : '#{src=classPhotoset}'},
        { src : "#{src=tiny247}", href : '#{src=full247}', class : '#{src=classPhotoset}'}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved much easier, without the tasks outlined in the question. The array (or object) `available Imgs` assigned the values of the array (or object) pug `projectTemplate` in this way:

```
script.
    availableImgs = !{JSON.stringify(projectTemplate)};
```

I hope this helps someone!